# avoid strip whitespace in child node

Tags: xslt-1.0

I want output with spaces however I want to keep `<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>` as well in the xslt. Presently, out by below XSLT is "onetwofour" that is without spaces. If I remove `<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>` tag output will be as expected that is "one two  four" (note two spaces between word two & four one extra space is due to subitem3)

Note: "subitem3" tag has one space, which should be retain in output.

Is there any way i can keep `<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>` tag and have spaces also (so output should be like this =>"one two  four").

If that is not possible due to inclusion of xsl:strip-space on top at least space for subitem3 can it be retain (so expected output in this case  can be "onetwo four" notice space before word 'four' due to subitem3)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
<xsl:template match="item">
    <xsl:for-each select="child::node()">
                    <xsl:choose>
                            <xsl:when test="name() = 'some_tag'">
                                <!-- Do nothing for now -->
                            </xsl:when>                         
                            <xsl:otherwise>
                                <xsl:value-of select="descendant-or-self::text()"/> 
                            </xsl:otherwise>
                        </xsl:choose>
                </xsl:for-each>


</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<items>
    <item>
        <subitem1>one</subitem1> <subitem2>two</subitem2> <subitem3> </subitem3> <subitem4>four</subitem4>
    </item>
</items>
```

present output:
**onetwofour**

Expected Output:
 **one two  four** OR
**onetwo four**

Comment: Your question is incomprehensible: your stylesheet matches nothing in your input, and you don't tell us what your output **should** be.

Comment: Please see my question again, hope it makes more sense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to retain a text node that contains only whitespace characters, then either do not use:

```
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
```

or override it by:

```
<xsl:preserve-space elements="subitem3"/>
```

---

Alternatively, you could insert your own spaces when writing to the output tree - for example:

```
<xsl:template match="item">
    <xsl:for-each select="*">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/> 
        <xsl:if test="not(string())"> 
            <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: but what if we have multiple whitespace in the tag, your solution is on assumption that subitem3 has only one whitespace but I need generic solution.that retains number of whitespace. But preserve space is working..Thanks for the help